# How to calculate the total sum on list in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

if i using this StreamBuilder to call my snapshot.data.document

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('col')
            .document('doc')
            .snapshots(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return new Container(
              child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            Data(document: snapshot.data.documents),
          }
        },
      ),
```

and I call this score value data in my class Data() to ListView.builder

```
ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0, bottom: 50.0),
      itemCount: document.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
         int score = document[i].data['score'];
      }
```

> how to get the sum total from that data and display it in AlertDialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Future getTotal() async {
    int counter = 0;
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection('post').document('doc').collection('collection')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((data) =>
        data.documents.forEach((doc) => counter += (doc["score"])));
    print("The total is $counter");
    return counter;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but, this is my result : 
`I/flutter (18264): Total Score : null
E/flutter (18264): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '+' was called on null.
E/flutter (18264): Receiver: null
E/flutter (18264): Tried calling: +(5)
`

Comment: ohh sorry, I have updated the answer. Please check now

Comment: i don't know why but, the result is same as the static value $counter

Comment: thanks a lot sir, this is work, but that 'await' doesn't work on me `Await only futures.` and make the result sometimes 0 and sometimes get the correct result in my AlertDialog, i think that was because the code is not wait that counting, how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

for future users, you can use `fold` functions.

```
Future getTotal() async {
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection('post').document('doc').collection('collection')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((data) =>
        counter = data.documents.fold(0, (prev, current)) => prev + current.score;
    print("The total is $counter");
    return counter;
  }
}
```